# Using HTML form to generate input results in a new tab

Tags: html, forms

I am new to the coding world and I have an idea to assist me in my job. I would like to create a form that could display the results in a new tab so they can be copy/pasted. I have basic understanding of HTML and CSS at this point.

My challenge is that I can only use notepad to write the code and use Microsoft Edge as the browser to display. I cannot setup a server side to send the information inputted.

I don't even know if what I am trying to accomplish is even possible.

Could some one point me in the correct direction to tell me what I would require to make this possible? Or if it is actually possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using your local storage.
Here there are 2 files: index.html & Confirm.html. Make sure both are in the same folder.

> index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function tosubmit() {
            var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
            localStorage.setItem("mytext", mytext);
            return true;
        }

    </script> 
</head>
<body>
        <form name="myform" onsubmit="tosubmit();" action="confirm.html">
            <input  id="mytext" type="text" name="data">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> confirm.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function init() {
        var mytext = localStorage.getItem("mytext");
        document.write(mytext);
    }
</script>
</head>    
<body onload="init();">
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this solved your problem.

Comment: Modified your code to fit my current ids
When I click submit it can see the information is relayed in the address bar.
The page itself though only displays "null"
Also if i would have multiple inputs I would have to create a var for each? on both pages?

Comment: Modified your code to fit my current ids
When I click submit it can see the information is relayed in the address bar.
The page itself though only displays "null"
Also if i would have multiple inputs I would have to create a var for each? on both pages?
I copy/pasted your code into their own respective files in the same folder as my own project. Opened the pages in Edge and your code worked. I am trying to figure out why it will not work with mine. Could it be because the inputs are nested in div elements on multiple layers> I am using CSS grid to position my inputs on the page.